# Añadir a Inno Setup un instalador de Java en caso tal de que la Pc no cuente con Java

Tags: java, inno-setup

**¡Muy buenas a todos nuevamente!**

Veran, Resulta que ya he finalizado un proyecto creado en **Java**, El cual al comprimirlo en .jar, lo convierto a un .exe con: [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) en el cual hago que  dependa de el **Bundled JRE** para asi usando el **Inno Setup** me lo comprima todo en un instalador y que el cliente no tenga que preocuparse por nada mas que dar a siguiente y siguiente, pero sucede que de tan solo **11 Mb** aprox de peso pasa a **500 Mb** aprox gracias a tener el JRE integrado, **Entonces mi pregunta es:** conocen algun metodo o funcion del Inno Setup que pueda verificar cada maquina y mostrar un Instalador de Java que baje los datos desde la web y lo instale de ser necesario?, **Gracias de antemano y ojala puedan ayudarme.**

Aqui dejo el codigo del Instalador que en mayor parte me ha generado el Inno setup pero con el JRE integrado:

```
#define MyAppName "EAM Consultores - Clientes"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "Extibax"
#define MyAppURL "https://twitter.com/extibax"
#define MyAppExeName "EAM Consultores - Clientes.exe"

[Setup]
AppId={{DFCE4562-C51B-4897-94AE-32693342F5AA}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputDir=C:\Users\SrExtibax\Desktop
OutputBaseFilename=EAM Setup 1.0
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\SrExtibax\Desktop\Work\CustomersManager\favicon.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "spanish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\SrExtibax\Desktop\Work\CustomersManager\EAM Consultores - Clientes.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\SrExtibax\Desktop\Work\CustomersManager\subJRE\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\SrExtibax\Desktop\Work\CustomersManager\subLib\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

[Dirs]
Name: {app}; Permissions: users-full

[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commonstartup}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el metodo de compresion utilizado por 7-Zip `LZMA2` con el nivel `ultra64`

```
[Setup]
SolidCompression=yes
Compression=lzma2/ultra64
```

> Asegurate de compilarlo desde una maquina de 64Bits